# XPath query or XSLT to get all namespace-URIs used in an XML document

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XSLT: How to get a list of all used namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747049/xslt-how-to-get-a-list-of-all-used-namespaces)

Given an XML Document that uses namespaces, is there an XPath query or XSLT that returns all the Namespace-URIs?

Comment: Thanks for finding that, it looks like that is what I want; still need to find out the prefixes, but it gives me a good start.

Comment: Your questions doesn't talk about prefixes... Besides that, a `fn:name()` call for a namespace node results in the prefix. But do note that prefix could be bounded to different URIs in different contexts of the document.

Comment: I figured both (that I needed prefixes, and that those prefixes can be different in the tree) after I read some of the XSLT queries. Thanks for confirming the latter.